# Monitorando a última row de uma tabela

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Estou tentando monitorar a última `row` de um banco `MySQL` e quando esta for alterada eu vou exibir uma mensagem, porem estou com dúvidas em como monitorar com código C#.

Já consegui requisitar a última `row` de tempo em tempo, porém gostaria de exibi-lá somente se for diferente da anterior.

Esta primeira parte inicia meu contador juntamente com o `Load` do Form:

```
private void AnteSala_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var timer = new System.Timers.Timer
    {
        Interval = 2 * 60 * 1000,
        SynchronizingObject = this
    };
    timer.Elapsed += delegate
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(@"tentou update check 1");
        ReadInformationFromeMessage();
        //MessageBox.Show(@"passou 1");
    };
    timer.Start();
}
```

Esta segunda parte pega minha última `row` mensagem do banco:

```
private void ReadInformationFromeMessage()
{
    try
    {
        const string mySelectQuery =
            "select * from send_eMessages order by id desc limit 1";
        var myCommand = new MySqlCommand(mySelectQuery, ConexaoBancoMySql.GetConexao());
        var reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var eMessage = (reader.GetString("eMessage"));

            Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {

               var pop = new PopupNotifier
               {
                   //escopo de mensagem
                   TitleText = "*  Informativo de Segurança  *",
                   ContentText = "" + eMessage,
                   //fim do escopo de mensagem
                   TitleFont = new Font("Tahoma", 12),
                   //cor do titulo do form
                   TitleColor = Color.White,
                   BodyColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0, 75, 0),
                   //contorno do form
                   BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 0),
                   //cor da fonte do aviso
                   ContentColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255),
                   //tamanho da fonte
                   ContentFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 12F),
                   //cor da fonte do aviso quando mouse em cima
                   ContentHoverColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255),
                   //centralizacao da mensagem no form 
                   ImagePadding = new Padding(0),
                   ContentPadding = new Padding(10),
                   Delay = 15000,
                   GradientPower = 150,
                   //tamanho da borda superior
                   HeaderHeight = 1,
                   Scroll = true,
                   ShowCloseButton = true,
                   ShowGrip = true,
                   ShowOptionsButton = false,                      
               };
                pop.Popup();
           });
        }
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        ConexaoBancoMySql.FecharConexao();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A pergunta não ficou clara pra mim, mas não tenho pontuação para comentar. Então vou responder baseado em que eu entendi.

Neste caso eu faria uma `DataTable` de cache histórico, onde toda vez que você que fizesse a consulta salvasse os dados nesta tabela de cache, e depois, compararia o retorno de dados da consulta atual com os dados do cache.

```
public void sample(){

    DataTable cache = /* sua tabela de cache */;
    DataTable consultaAtual = /* retorno da sua consulta atual */;

    foreach(DataRow rowCache in cache.Rows){
        foreach(DataRow rowConsultaAtual in consultaAtual.Rows){
            /* abaixo você vai comparar todas as colunas da linha da consulta atual com as colunas da linha do cache */
            if(rowCache["column1"].toString().Equals(rowConsultaAtual["column1"])){
                /* os valores das colunas da consulta atual e do cache estão iguais, então não houve modificação */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Não sei se era isso que você queria, caso não seja excluo a resposta. Sou iniciante e estou tentando aprender ajudando, espero que te ajude :)

Comment: Tudo bem @caio porem ja obtive respostas no overflow , mesmo assim obrigado